# Multiple calling of getView() in GridView

Tags: android

My Activity consists of GridView which holds 40+ elements. After starting activity user could see maximum 15 items (3 rows, 5 items in each row). I wrote in getView() body to pass to the LogCat number of getting View:

```
Log.i("getView()", "GETTING VIEW_POSITION[" + String.valueOf(position) + "]" + (convertView != null?convertView.toString():"null"));
```

After launching my app I get such log:

```
02-09 14:34:56.900: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[0]null
02-09 14:34:57.300: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[0]android.widget.FrameLayout@44c7a9c0  
02-09 14:34:57.300: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[1]null
02-09 14:34:57.400: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[2]null
02-09 14:34:57.510: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[3]null
02-09 14:34:57.620: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[4]null
02-09 14:34:57.720: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[5]null
02-09 14:34:57.840: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[6]null
02-09 14:34:57.930: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[7]null
02-09 14:34:58.273: DEBUG/dalvikvm(388): GC freed 3530 objects / 322744 bytes in 270ms
02-09 14:34:58.280: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[8]null
02-09 14:34:58.300: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[9]null
02-09 14:34:58.320: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[10]null
02-09 14:34:58.340: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[11]null
02-09 14:34:58.360: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[12]null
02-09 14:34:58.380: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[13]null
02-09 14:34:58.400: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[14]null
02-09 14:34:59.220: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[0]null
02-09 14:34:59.490: INFO/getView()(388): GETTING VIEW_POSITION[0]android.widget.FrameLayout@44c69ef0
```

I also red [this](http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=12889) post about such kind of issue. But My GridView's height in XML  description set as fill parent:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<GridView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:id="@+id/grid"
                android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
                android:layout_height="fill_parent"
                android:numColumns="auto_fit"
                android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
                android:verticalSpacing="10dp"
                android:columnWidth="140dp"
                android:gravity="center"
                android:scrollbars="none"
                />
```

And finally to remove all doubts, here is my Adapter code:

```
public class ImageAdapter extends BaseAdapter
    {
        private Activity activity;
        private LayoutInflater inflater = null;
        private ArrayList<Photo> photoes;
        
        public ImageAdapter(Activity a, ArrayList<Photo> pictures)
        {
            photoes = pictures;
            activity = a;
            inflater = (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent)
        {
            Log.i("getView()", "GETTING VIEW_POSITION[" + String.valueOf(position) + "]" + (convertView != null?convertView.toString():"null"));
                View mViewSlice = convertView;
                if(convertView == null) {
                    mViewSlice = inflater.inflate(R.layout.photo_preview, null);
                    ((TextView) mViewSlice.findViewById(R.id.name_of_photo)).setText(photoes.get(position).getName());
                    
                    mViewSlice.setPadding(5, 5, 5, 5);
                    mViewSlice.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(-2, -2));
                    
                }
        
               
                      
               return mViewSlice;
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return photoes.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return photoes.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }   
    }
```

I hope somebody will respond at my problem and will help me to solve it.

Waiting for your suggestions. Alex.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The response on that link if quite clear I think

> There is absolutely no guarantee on
>   the number of times getView() will be
>   invoked for any given position

Now this remark also implies you shouldn't use `wrap_content`

> usually occurs with lists and grids
>   that have a height set to wrap_content

But that does not mean it would not happen for other situations. The bug was closed as "WorkingAsIntended", so I don't think you can do too much. It's just something that can happen.

Comment: Romain said for any given position. But I'm sure, that I'm not the first man who found this problem applying to only the first position in GridView. And I repeat again, as you can see from my XML, I don't use wrap_content.

Comment: What i mean to say is that even though there is mention of wrap_content, there is no mention of something like that **never** occuring with fill_parent. So there is no need to repeat what you said, I got you the first time. I just don't agree that it matters :D. Now why it's only the first position I don't know, but the first position is part of "any given position". So as I read the answer, its still behaviour as expected.

Comment: Could you explain, what do you mean when say, that the first position is the part of any given position?

Comment: When you say something can happen to "any given position", it automatically includes that you say it can happen for the first position (or the second, or the third). The fact that it can happen to any position, does not mean that it should happen to all posistions, just that it is a posibility that it might happen to all. So it happening to the first is the behaviour that was explained to be 'normal' or expected.

Comment: Yes, I agree but this "normal" behaviour is observed only with first positions in every cases that I saw.

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to say. The behaviour you observe is in line with the behaviour explained as 'normal'. So as long as there are no reasons to think otherwise, I really can't see what could be done here. I'm not trying to be a smartass or anything, I just don't see it...

Comment: You know, I think I found the issue. If you try to equate your view to a convert view gridview call the first item more then twice. It works well if you don't interact with convert view. And also it's better to define your view as final.

Comment: @teoREtik I have the same issue, and this is crazy, this is major hole in the design they didn't bother to fix, since in most cases it works... my first item is called hundreds of times, which is unacceptable, what was your solution again, hoping you would remember :)

Answer (score 6):

For me, it's even worse: 0 position is called often 10 times. And it's called even if I'm at the end of the list, without position 0 on the screen.

My solution is a static ArrayList of items being currently processed for display and I ignore those double-calls. It's not the best solution though as it still uses resources to get 0 position while it's even not on the screen.

As it seems like a bug, I think I will cache a View for position 0 so it would get a quick and proper return value even if the position is not on the screen.

Android 4.2.2.

Comment: Then you are lucky, in my case its called 33 times for position 0. I will implement the cache for view 0, as you said.

Answer (score -6):

I had the same Problem, my solution was to create a List outside the Adapter, then give the List to the Adapter, something like that:

```
    class MyAdapter extends BaseAdapter{

    List<View> views;

    public MyAdapter(List<View> views){
        this.views = views;
    }

    ...

    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){
        return views.get(position);     // now your safe even if element[0] is called n times
    }
}

class MyActivity extends Activity{

    GridView grid;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        List<View> views = create_your_views():

        MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(views);

        grid.setAdapter(adapter);           
    }
}
```

Comment: This is just the usual way you set data in the adapter and doesn't have any relation with the described problem.