# GridView is calling "position 0" twice

Tags: android, gridview, baseadapter, custom-adapter

I'm building a GridView of cards, using CustomAddapter-ArrayList.
Every cell contains 2 imageViews (only one is visible per click-front or back of a card).
For "flipping" I use animation.
The code works fine, the only cell that won't flip with animation is the cell with the position 0 (image1 will change to image2 but no animation).
Then I noticed something that might be the reason for it,
position 0 is called twice in getView for every click

```
I/System.out: position: 0
I/System.out: position: 0
I/System.out: position: 1
I/System.out: position: 2
I/System.out: position: 3
... // up to 20
```

I tried to find answers on this website but they kept talking about the layout height and it didn't help.
Can you please help me?

**CustomAdapter:**

```
public class CustomAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Square> {

final AnimatorSet setRightOut;
final AnimatorSet setLeftIn;

public CustomAdapter(GameActivity context, ArrayList<Square> list) {
    super(context, 0, list);

    setRightOut = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
            R.animator.flip_right_out);
    setLeftIn = (AnimatorSet) AnimatorInflater.loadAnimator(context,
            R.animator.flight_left_in);
}

class ViewHolder {
    public ImageView img1,img2; //img1=card's back, img2=card's front (random pic)
}

public View getView (int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent){

    ViewHolder viewHolder;
    if (convertView == null)
    {
    convertView= LayoutInflater.from(getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    viewHolder=new ViewHolder();
    viewHolder.img1 = (ImageView)
    convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
    viewHolder.img2 = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView2);
    convertView.setTag(viewHolder);//setting random pic}

    else{viewHolder= (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();}

    System.out.println("position: " + position);
    viewHolder.img2.setImageResource(getItem(position).id);

        if (getItem(position).selected == 1) { //first flip

            setRightOut.setTarget( viewHolder.img1);
            setLeftIn.setTarget( viewHolder.img2);
            setRightOut.start();
            setLeftIn.start();
            getItem(position).selected = 2;  }

       else (getItem(position).selected == 2) //card was flipped already- stay flipped 
           {
            viewHolder.img2.setAlpha(1.0f);
            viewHolder.img1.setAlpha(0.0f);
           }

    return convertView;
}}
```

**activity layout:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:id="@+id/activity_game"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:background="#0f49b4"
tools:context="com.example.memory.GameActivity">


<GridView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="410dp"
    android:numColumns="4"
    android:background="#d5e2e1"
    android:id="@+id/gridView"
 </GridView>

</LinearLayout>
```

**row xml:**

```
?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="100dp"
android:layout_height="80dp">

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView"
    android:src="@drawable/q"/>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="100dp"
    android:layout_height="80dp"
    android:id="@+id/imageView2"
    android:alpha="0"
 />
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a very old behavior, Check this SO link - [Multiple calling of getView() in GridView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4946527/multiple-calling-of-getview-in-gridview)

Your only bet would be to retain a queue of flip actions (just chose a set data structure or something) and fill it up in `onClick` and then in the next `getView` pass, check the content of this queue and handle flipping if required. Once handled, remove that entry from your queue. This is just to ensure that you don't end up flipping twice.

Due to the nature of `Gridview` (specially with childs which has a wrap_content attribute for it's bounds), it's kinds risky too keep non-idempotent code in `getView`.

Unfortunately I learned the same by facing the exact problem but albeit with an `ExpandableListView`.

Comment: The queue won't help in my case. My card doesn't flip twice, I guess it has not enough time to flip the first call- it already jumps to the second call- and it means it will jump to the second condition which keeps the card flipped- "else (getItem(position).selected == 2" . I should keep playing with conditions I guess, but I feel it wrong. Where else should I create the animation if not in the adapter?